# Flutter || Checkbox on hover doesn't give on tap cursor permission

Tags: flutter, checkbox, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am working on dropdownmenu items where in the drop-down menu item there are several checkboxes but any of the checkboxes on hover don't give on tap cursor permission.
This is a very strange thing I found out as I have already used the checkbox before but this type of error I didn't receive.
I think maybe the problem is in dropdownmenu.

I have also included the video for better understanding of my problem.

[image]

my code :-

```
Container(
    width: 160,
    //margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5), color: Colors.white),
    child: ListTileTheme(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      dense: true,
      horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
      minLeadingWidth: 0,
      child: ExpansionTile(
        iconColor: primaryBackgroundLightGrey,
        title: Text(
            listOFSelectedItem.isEmpty
                ? "Project type"
                : listOFSelectedItem[0],
            style: t5O40),
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 10,
            color: primaryBackgroundLightGrey,
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: widget.listOFStrings.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                    child: _ViewItem(
                        item: widget.listOFStrings[index],
                        selected: (val) {
                          selectedText = val;
                          if (listOFSelectedItem.contains(val)) {
                            listOFSelectedItem.remove(val);
                          } else {
                            listOFSelectedItem.add(val);
                          }
                          widget.selectedList(listOFSelectedItem);
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        itemSelected: listOFSelectedItem
                            .contains(widget.listOFStrings[index])),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),

    class _ViewItem extends StatelessWidget {
  String item;
  bool itemSelected;
  final Function(String) selected;

  _ViewItem(
      {required this.item, required this.itemSelected, required this.selected});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: size.width * .015,
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 2,
            width: 2,
            child: Checkbox(
                value: itemSelected,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  selected(item);
                },
                hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                checkColor: Colors.white,
                activeColor: Colors.grey),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: size.width * .010,
          ),
          Text(item, style: t3O60),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: there is a different between onchanged and onTap.

Comment: @pmatatias checkbox only onchanged parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt the example to your own code

```
dropdownBuilder: _customDropDownExample,
popupItemBuilder: _customPopupItemBuilderExample,

Widget _customDropDownExample(
  BuildContext context, UserModel? item, String itemDesignation) {
if (item == null) {
  return Container();
}

return Container(
  child: (item.avatar == null)
      ? ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          leading: CircleAvatar(),
          title: Text("No item selected"),
        )
      : ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          leading: CircleAvatar(
              // this does not work - throws 404 error
              // backgroundImage: NetworkImage(item.avatar ?? ''),
              ),
          title: Text(item.name),
          subtitle: Text(
            item.createdAt.toString(),
          ),
        ),
);
```

After that

```
Widget _customPopupItemBuilderExample(
  BuildContext context, UserModel item, bool isSelected) {
return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
  decoration: !isSelected
      ? null
      : BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
  child: ListTile(
    selected: isSelected,
    title: Text(item.name),
    subtitle: Text(item.createdAt.toString()),
    leading: CircleAvatar(
        // this does not work - throws 404 error
        // backgroundImage: NetworkImage(item.avatar ?? ''),
        ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this package https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2
Multiselect Dropdown with Checkboxes

```css
final List<String> items = [
  'Item1',
  'Item2',
  'Item3',
  'Item4',
];
List<String> selectedItems = [];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton2(
          isExpanded: true,
          hint: Align(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            child: Text(
              'Select Items',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14,
                color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          items: items.map((item) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: item,
              //disable default onTap to avoid closing menu when selecting an item
              enabled: false,
              child: StatefulBuilder(
                builder: (context, menuSetState) {
                  final _isSelected = selectedItems.contains(item);
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      _isSelected
                              ? selectedItems.remove(item)
                              : selectedItems.add(item);
                      //This rebuilds the StatefulWidget to update the button's text
                      setState(() {});
                      //This rebuilds the dropdownMenu Widget to update the check mark
                      menuSetState(() {});
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: double.infinity,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          _isSelected
                                  ? const Icon(Icons.check_box_outlined)
                                  : const Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank),
                          const SizedBox(width: 16),
                          Text(
                            item,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
          //Use last selected item as the current value so if we've limited menu height, it scroll to last item.
          value: selectedItems.isEmpty ? null : selectedItems.last,
          onChanged: (value) {},
          buttonHeight: 40,
          buttonWidth: 140,
          itemHeight: 40,
          itemPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          selectedItemBuilder: (context) {
            return items.map(
                      (item) {
                return Container(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                  child: Text(
                    selectedItems.join(', '),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                    maxLines: 1,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ).toList();
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```